# Android drawable error not shown

Tags: android, eclipse, drawable

How can you force an **error** to be shown in the eclipse console? I mean the kind of error which is generated when a `drawable` has an **invalid name** or something is not correct with the `R.java`.

Comment: can you please paste you error log?

Comment: I get it at random times. That's the problem now... that I'm not getting the error anymore while the project is still indicated to contain errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, Errors from the R.java class are caused by two reasons:
1.project properties are broken.
2.errors that come from xml files.

for the first issue you can do:
right click on the project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties
restart eclipse / Project > Clean

Errors that shown in xml files are from the ADT.
ADT error information can be found in:
Eclipse > Window > Show View > Error Log .

Answer (score 0):

Just go into the error log of eclipse  Window-->Show view -->Error log , then post the error